# Update array with Composition api

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue with Pinia store installed.

```
export default {
  setup() {
    let rows: Row[] = store.history.rows;
  }
}
```

This works fine, but later I want to overwrite the array and filter it:

```
 const filterArray = () => {
      rows=store.history.rows;
       for (let index = 0; index < rows.length; index++){
        if (rows[index].department !== departmentModel.value) {
           rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    };
```

Somehow the `filterArray` method removes the objects from the `store.history.rows` array as well, so both of the arrays will be empty soon.
What I want to archive is every time the `filterArray` is called, the `rows` array will be overwritten by the `store.history.row`s array (which contains all of the objects) and then the `rows` array will be filtered based on the if statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this composition api or options api? (https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles)

Comment: composition api

Comment: you're making a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) when you need to make a deep copy

Comment: @yoduh FWIW, `rows=store.history.rows`  is not a shallow copy but rather reference to the same array. `rows = [...store.history.rows]` is a shallow copy, which is fine as long as the array items themselves are not getting mutated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set `rows = store.history.rows` it doesn't make a copy of the array. It just ends up working like a pointer, referencing the same array.

You can avoid that by making a copy of the array before you proceed mutating it

```
rows = [...store.history.rows];
```

Or you use functional conventions, which IMHO is the preferred way anyway.

```js
const filterArray = () => {
  rows = store.history.rows.filter(item => item.department === departmentModel.value)
}
```

this will create a new array of items that match a given `departmentModel.value`.