# Filter method gives back a proxy array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to filter an array of objects using Vue Composition API. I'm using `filter` method, but it changes the output, so my app crashes.
My code looks like this:

```
rows = store.history.rows;
let items = rows.filter(item => item.department == item.department); //I know this will be always true
console.log(rows);
console.log(items);
```

The output will be totally different, that's why I cant use it...
[image]

How could I properly filter the rows without changing the output?

Comment: Have you tried: `rows = [...store.history.rows];`?

Comment: Why filter if you know the conditional will always be true?

Comment: Just to console.log and show that they have the same content

Comment: It was already answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74316905/update-array-with-composition-api) you need to deep copy the array.  `rows = store.history.rows` is only a shallow copy